# using pure query on zend pagination

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

so I've been using Zend Pagination, and I don't like the fact that I have to keep on using the Zend_DB_Select object to paginate things...

I want to just use a raw select query

```
"SELECT * FROM db etc etc"
```

and then pass that query into zend pagination without converting it to zend db select

is it possible to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dislike `Zend_DB_Select` for your pagination, no-one stops you from writing what you want as your own `Zend_Paginator_Adapter_Interface`. See [Zend Pagination Advanced Usage](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.paginator.advanced.html), but take care you do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: yea...is there a wheel already existing for putting a raw query in?

Comment: That's what `Zend_DB_Select` is for, so just take care you really need something different. You should probably better explain why you need this, so this can be better answered.

Comment: no in Zend db select you have to create the object and then call a whole bunch of methods that correspond to the query eg $sql->join() etc.....what I'm trying to do is just use the query AS IS without using those methods...

Comment: @kamikaze_pilot: Probably there is a solution that creates such an object from an SQL string? Would be a more straight forward solution in my eyes. Something like and SQL to Zend_DB_Select converter. Maybe this leads you to some ideas: http://zend-framework-community.634137.n4.nabble.com/raw-SQL-to-Zend-Db-Select-td2271145.html

Comment: One of the advantages of Zend_Db_Select in this situation is that it's much easier to modify a query object to add a limit, remove group bys and change selected columns to just COUNT(*); than it is to do the same thing to an SQL string.